# SAML2 metadata without SLS

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, shibboleth

How do I correctly indicate inside of the SP metadata that this SP does not support SLS?

I removed the `<md:SingleLogoutService ...>` element from the metadata. But now on the logout page Shibboleth still attempts to use SLS and in the log I see the following:

`WARN [net.shibboleth.idp.saml.profile.impl.PopulateBindingAndEndpointContexts:410] - Profile Action PopulateBindingAndEndpointContexts: Unable to resolve outbound message endpoint for relying party 'entity-id-comes-here': EndpointCriterion [type={urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata}SingleLogoutService, trusted=false]`

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's related to the SingleLogoutService removal?
You should turn on DEBUG [logging](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/IDP30/LoggingConfiguration), and see if anything comes up.

I had the same error, and it was due to a mismatch between the metadata and the SP callback(wrong URL...)

Comment: The preceding log line states: `2017-11-29 18:58:04,766 - DEBUG [org.opensaml.saml.common.binding.AbstractEndpointResolver:130] - Endpoint Resolver org.opensaml.saml.common.binding.impl.DefaultEndpointResolver: No candidate endpoints met criteria`

Comment: And, yes, I am pretty sure that the mentioned in the warning `SingleLogoutService` is not specified in the SP meta :(